# Is there a (creative) way to hide a text field in Indesign if there is no information in the data merge field?

Tags: textfield, adobe-indesign

I am creating a data-merge document in InDesign.

There are various tables that I've created which only show as many rows as there is actual data in the field, through some creative table and cell styles.

Now I've been asked to only have an entirely separate table only show if there is information in any of those fields.

I'm at a total loss.  With the way the current structure is set up, I can cause it to not display any text, but it still shows empty header cells and one line of empty row cells.

[Pre-DataMerge, with the data fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EECVb.jpg)

[Post-Datamerge, with the resulting empty cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9osIX.jpg)

Any creative ideas to hide that table?  I was thinking there might be a way to hide the entire text field, if not the table.  Maybe a script?  I tried one that deletes blank tables, but that didn't seem to work after the data-merge was run.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can get that level of processing with InDesign datamerge. You could think of a script to post remove those tables or use a dedicated plugin such as Easycatalog that can take care of such empty items natively.